# Create Postgres policy that compares value being inserted with existing values

Tags: postgresql

Assume the following table `animals`:

| name | version | owner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 1 | a |
| cat | 2 | a |

There is a unique index on (name, version).

Only the owner of a particular animal name should be able to insert new versions.

If user `b` performs the following insert, it should fail:
`insert into animals (name, version) values ('cat', 3);`

If user `a` performs the same insert, it should succeed.

If any user performs the following insert, it should succeed:
`insert into animals (name, version) values ('dog', 1);`

Assume the function `current_user()` returns `a`.

What policy could be used to effect this requirement?

The following policy doesn't work (I think because `name = name` is always true):

```
create policy animal_version_owner on animals as permissive for
INSERT WITH CHECK (
    exists (select 1 from animals where name = name and owner = current_user())
);
```

I want to do something like name = NEW.name. The manual says:

> Note that the check_expression is evaluated against the proposed new
> contents of the row, not the original contents

I don't fully understand that. Is it not possible to select existing records from the database and then compare those to the values being inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stumbled upon the [same problem recently](https://github.com/docteurklein/pgpim/blob/55632c6c8d0df5b3bfc65181dfc0dafc54970c2c/src/schema.sql#L171) and noticed you can disambiguate which `name` you're talking about by using aliases and original relation name.

I'd try something like:

```sql
create policy animal_version_owner on animals as permissive
for insert
with check (
    exists (select from animals a where a.name = animals.name and a.owner = current_user())
);
```

I agree it's complicated to be sure how policies work, especially when you mix permissive and restrictive, `using` and `check`, but one way to help debug them is to use `EXPLAIN`, you'll see the applied filters in the output.

I'd also recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__NKfEfvYuI by Stephen Frost, one of the main contributors of RLS if I'm not mistaken.

As a last resort, you can always try to write the check as a trigger.